# How does one uninstall Xcode 7.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I recently installed Xcode 7.0.1 under OS-X 10.11.  That was a mistake.  My MacBook Air 13-inch system with an i7 processor, 8GB of RAM and 512GB SSD could not handle Xcode 7.0.1.  It was slow, buggy and occupies 8.8GB of disk storage.  I have concluded I want to uninstall Xcode 7.0.1 and continue with my Java development work.  I'll use Xcode again when they improve the IDE.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Xcode 7 works good on my MacBook Air with i5 and 4 gb ram, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks egor.zhdan for your comment, given your i5 and 4 db ram.  It gives me hope that I may be able to overcome my problems with a very slow, high CPU-intensive utilization (0% Idle Process Time) using Xcode 7.0.1.  I have filed multiple Bug Reports with Apple Development but will now further investigate why the poor performance on my 13" Air with 8gb RAM, i7 processor and 512gb ssd.  I simply do not know the answer to your comment at this point.